# Monitor MongoDB Replica Set members States using Datadog Agent

Tags: mongodb, datadog

How to monitor the state of MongoDB Replica Set members using Datadog agent?
And by state I mean whether the node is Primary, Secondary, Arbiter.., and that in order to send an alert when the state changes.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: facing same issue, were you able to find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

With a Replica Set there are metrics that need to be collected only once (like the number of collections) and metrics that needs to be collected from every node. For this to happen, [according to the docs](https://docs.datadoghq.com/integrations/mongo/?tab=replicaset#configure-the-agents), you need to set up one check instance for each member of the replica set.

```
init_config:
instances:
    - hosts:
        - primary_host:<PORT>
      username: foo
      password: bar
      ....
    - hosts:
        - secondary_host:<PORT>
      username: foo
      password: bar
      ....
```

The check figures out if the node is a primary or secondary and collects accordingly. Metrics from replica sets will be tagged with replset_name and replset_state.

Comment: In fact I receive the status as mongodb.replset.state for each member, but I couldn't create an alert in Datadog cloud interface since there is no = operator when defining the alert trigger, there is only >, <..., and I want for example when mongodb.replset.state=3 then send an alert..